# Raw twig variable filter within a short if

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I am using **short conditional** to discriminate the values ​​displayed in a list of records.

For example if I want the name of the customers who have a greater than 100 identifier are **emphasized** (`<em> </em>`) perform the following:

```
{# Displays the identifier of the client #}
{% set strClient = '<em>' ~ client.name ~ '</em>' %}
{{ Client.id > 100 ? strClient|raw : client.name }}
```

**Here the HTML is processed** by the browser and customer name is displayed **emphasized**, the fact is that if for example you want to show your phone, which can be null or not, and if it is no display a message emphasized; I perform the following:

```
{# Displays the customer phone or message if there #}
{{ Client.id > 100 ? client.tel : '<em> Not found </em>' }}
```

In the latter case **HTML tags are not processed** by the browser and displayed as plain text, **I also tried** the following:

```
{# Displays the customer phone or message if there #}
{{ Client.id > 100 ? client.tel : '<em> Not found </em>'|raw }}
```

And this one:

```
{# Displays the customer phone or message if there #}
{% set strClient = '<em> Not found </em>' %}
{{ Client.id > 100 ? client.tel : strClient|raw }}
```

With the same result, ie when is a string, this stored in a variable or do not get the HTML tags that **always appear as if it were processed plaintext**.

**Does anyone know how to get the HTML string in a twig be interpreted?**

Comment: From the twig doc, Twig does not escape static expressions:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the raw filter with a tenary if you need to wrap the whole statement in brackets for it to work.

E.g. `{{ (Client.id > 100 ? client.tel : '<em> Not found </em>')|raw }}`

Comment: Thanks,**works perfectly**. Quick and very clean solution, without having to put more blocks. **Greetings friend** :)

Answer (score 2):

In my tests on your example, none of the attempts worked, including your first example:

```
{# Displays the identifier of the client #}
{% set strClient = '<em>' ~ client.name ~ '</em>' %}
{{ Client.id > 100 ? strClient|raw : client.name }}
```

However, if you wrap your examples with `{% autoescape false %}` and `{% endautoescape %}`, this should solve the issue. All of your examples should display as expected if wrapped like this:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{# Displays the customer phone or message if there #}
{{ Client.id > 100 ? client.tel : '<em> Not found </em>' }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

No need for `|raw` if using autoescape.

Comment: This solution also **works** but it seems that much dirty code having to be opening and closing blocks, anyway thank you very much for answering. **Greetings friend** :)